# Replace hex delimiter and extra characters at the end of file in UNIX

Tags: unix

I've non-printable delimiters (`^\`) and  (`^^`) at the end of each line in my UNIX file. I want to replace non-printable delimiter with printable delimiter like `|` and remove characters present at the end of each file.
How can I remove these characters?

Actual file:

```
1^\MI^\IN^\123^\Y^^
```

Expected output:

```
1|MI|IN|123|Y
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly what your non-printable characters are, so I will assume that you are using `^` to represent the character 0x1c and `^^` to represent 0x1e.

You can give octal sequences to `tr` to translate arbitrary characters, so if you want to delete the 0x1e and convert the 0x1c to `|`, you can do:

```
$ cat -v input
1^\MI^\IN^\123^\Y^^
$ xxd input
00000000: 311c 4d49 1c49 4e1c 3132 331c 591e 0a    1.MI.IN.123.Y..
$ < input tr -d '\036' | tr \\034 \| | cat -v
1|MI|IN|123|Y
```